# Linked Chart Populated by =NOW() Not Updating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace, google-slides-api

I have a slideshow on Google Slides running as our cafeteria slideshow. Recently, I got a Weather API to work and regularly update, using a linked chart. The chart and slide now updates automatically.

A student suggested that we add a real-time clock. Easy! I set it up in Charts using the =NOW() function and a scorecard chart, which displays just how I would like it. I linked it to the slide and set the trigger to run every minute, instead of every hour as I had done. The Sheet is set up to update every minute, and visibly does so. The Slides trigger fires, and the script runs successfully.

But Google Slides only notices that the Sheets chart has changed sporadically. Even if I unlink, create a new sheet, and re-link, it will still show the old time for an undetermined period of time. Here is my refreshCharts() function:

```
function refreshCharts(){
    var gotSlides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();

    for (var i = 0; i < gotSlides.length; i++) {
        var slide = gotSlides[i];
        var sheetsCharts = slide.getSheetsCharts();

        for (var k = 0; k < sheetsCharts.length; k++) {
            var shChart = sheetsCharts[k];
            shChart.refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I should add to tell Google that yes, I am changing this data as often as I claim I am? This has been working so cleanly for the Weather side that I was shocked when the linked chart refused to update here. Any clues as to what I might be missing?

Attached screenshot shows the current time discrepancy.
[Linked Chart Discrepancy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjSgG.png)

Comment: OK: I think Google doesn't recognize that the Sheet has changed. I can force it to update by typing something random in another cell elsewhere. Going to try writing a script with a trigger to jabber nearby & see if that lets the update go through.

Comment: That was it! Set a script/trigger to update a cell with a random animal name, and now Google Slides recognizes that the sheet has changed.

Comment: So, Jerry have you answered your own question (or is there a residual issue). Why not post an answer to your question? It might just help future users who have a problem similar to yours.

Comment: There is a residual issue, but related to Chrome Sign Builder and kiosk mode, so not apropos for here. I didn't post an answer because I hadn't seen the Answer Your Question button. Fixing now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The =NOW() function relies on recalculation (edited in File > Settings > Recalculation) to update the cell. This recalculation does not register as a change to the spreadsheet, so it does not trigger an update in the linked chart, even though the value changes.

I solved this by adding a counter that runs on a trigger; anything that changes a cell will do. Sample function:

```
function countMinutes() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var minutes = ss.getRange("E1");
  var plusMinute = minutes.getValue();
  minutes.setValue(plusMinute+1);
}
```